# Laravel 5.4 - Custom message for a dropdown list

Tags: php, laravel, validation, html-select, dropdown

I can create a validation custom message for a  text field but not for a .

Here is HTML for the "unit" field:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="unit" name="unit">
```

and here for the "visitor_id" field:

```
<select id="visitor_id" name="visitor_id" class="form-control">
    @foreach($visitors as $visitor)
        <option value="{{$visitor->id}}"> 
            {{ $visitor->name }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Controller:

```
$rules = [
   'unit'=> 'required|min:2|max:2',
   'visitor_id'=> 'required|not_in:14'
]
 $customMessages = [
    'unit.required' => 'Unit cannot be blank and must have 2 char max',
    'visitor_id.required' => 'Please choose from the list...'
    ];
$this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);
```

If I leave the unit field empty or don't follow the max:2 rule, the message will be what it should be: 'Unit cannot be blank..."

But if I leave the dropdown named visitor_id with the value of 14, the error message will be the default one "The selected visitor id is invalid." and not the one I need; "Please choose from the list..."

The attached image shows the result.

I researched for more than one hour and couldn't find a solution, unfortunately.

[image: error messages]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it will be the default message because you changed only for `required` and not for `not_in` so in order to make it work please add the following line under:

```
$rules = [
   'unit'=> 'required|min:2|max:2',
   'visitor_id'=> 'required|not_in:14'
]

 $customMessages = [
    'unit.required' => 'Unit cannot be blank and must have 2 char max',
    'visitor_id.required' => 'Please choose from the list...'
    'visitor_id.not_in' => 'Please choose from the list...' 
    ];

$this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);
```

Comment: Yes! That is it! I had already tried to do it joining them (visitor_id.required. not_in) but it never occurred to separate them. Thanks, Leo_Kelmendi

Answer (score 0):

I need to show the error message below the select field...My code is as follows.

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
  <select class="custom-select form-control" id="designation_id" value="{{old('designation_id')}}" name="designation_id">
     <option value="" class="disabled">-- Select Designation --</option>
         @foreach ($designations as $designation)
            <option value="{{ $designation->id }}"
                 @if(old('designation_id')== $designation->id) selected="selected" 
                 @endif> {{ $designation->name }} 
            </option>
         @endforeach
  </select>
</div>
```